# Ошибка в отправке письма на почту

Tags: php

Есть такой код отправки содержимого корзины на мыло. Почему каждый товар отправляется своим письмом (например, если в корзине 3 товара = 3 отдельных письма). Где ошибка? как исправить?

```
<?php
    require("includes/connection.php");
    $connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN(";
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
        $sql.=$id.",";
    }
    $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
    $query=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $totalprice=0;

    if(isset($_POST['order'])){
        $headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
        $headers .= 'From: Your name <info@address.com>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
            $subtotal=$_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quanity']*$row['price']; 
            $totalprice+=$subtotal;
            $content='
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <tr> 
                    <td>' .$row["name"]. '</td> 
                    <td>' .$row["id"] . $_SESSION["cart"][$row["id"]]["quanity"]. '"</td> 
                    <td>' .$row["price"]. '$</td> 
                    <td>' .$_SESSION["cart"][$row["id"]]["quanity"]*$row["price"]. '$</td> 
                </tr> 
            </body>
            </html>
            ';

            $message = $_POST['fio'].$content;
            $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
            mail($_POST['email'], 'My Subject', $message, $headers);
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$content');</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что у вас в цикле условие `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))` - дословно: сколько товаров в ответе БД mysql, столько раз повторить действие ниже между `{....}`, а в вашем случае отправку письма

**Решение**

Чтобы исправить, в цикле `while` сгенерируйте 1 письмо с нужным кол-вом товаров, а уже после отправьте письмо `mail($_POST['email'], 'My Subject', $message, $headers);`